# 'Future<dynamic>' has no instance getter 'body' error, when trying to access body of Future SmsMessage variable in Flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, asynchronous, dart

This is a class in a seperate file

```
import 'package:sms/sms.dart';

class SmsReader {
  SmsMessage sms;
  dynamic messageRead() async {
    SmsReceiver receiver = SmsReceiver();
    receiver.onSmsReceived.listen((SmsMessage msg) {
      sms = msg;
    });
    return sms;
  }
}
```

this file is where an object is created and func is called

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  SmsReader smsReader = SmsReader();
  dynamic sms;

  @override
  void initState() {
    sms = smsReader.messageRead();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Now when I try to 
`print(sms.body)`, this error appears

Class 'Future' has no instance getter 'body'.
Receiver: Instance of 'Future'
Tried calling: body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining `messageRead` as:

```dart
dynamic messageRead() async {
```

All `async` functions should return a `Future`, you are returning `dynamic` which defines that "every Type is ok here".

later you are calling `messageRead` without `await`, so it returns just a `Future`. You need to change your code to `await` `messageRead`:

```dart
Future<SmsMessage> messageRead() async {

...

SmsMessage sms;

...

smsReader.messageRead().then((newSms) => sms = newSms);
```

You need to use `then` instead of `await` as you can't `await` inside the `initState` function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The getter 'body' was called on null. This error occurs when I try to print the value of `sms.body` in build, eventhough a new message is recieved by the device. It used to work when the messageRead function was inside the that Stful widget.

Comment: That's another problem that's not related with your original question. I suggest you verify that `sms` isn't `null` before using it as the `Future` might not have finished before `build` is called. You make things easier by using a `FutureBuilder`.  I suggest you take a look on how `Futures` work, it seems to me that you are getting confused on the general theory behind them.

Comment: Sure. I tried using `smsReader.messageRead().then((newSms) => sms = newSms);` in a setState func inside Build, and it seems to work just fine. It does not work in `initState` only. The reason why I am trying to add it in `InitState` is, because I want it to keep running indefinitely, and update everytime a new message is recieved.

Comment: Again, you need to read more about `Future`. `Future` only runs once, only a `Stream` will return multiple values. Unless you keep calling more and more `Future`. `initState` can't use a `Future`, the `Future` result will arrive after `initState` completes. `initState` should only be used to setup a `Future` so other functions like `build` can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Do the change

```
  Future<dynamic> messageRead() async {
    SmsReceiver receiver = SmsReceiver();
      receiver.onSmsReceived.listen((SmsMessage msg) {
        sms = msg;
      });
    return sms;
  }
```

and

```
smsReader.messageRead().then((sms) { 
  //do whatever with sms ******
});
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks, this works! but when I when I store the value of sms in another variable say `message = sms`, and then `print(message.body)` it returns a null value.